# Why is my Salesforce-SOQL-Subquery-Query discarding entrie

Tags: apex, soql, query

**UPDATE**

It seems that this issue only occures if the for-each-loop handles more than one entry. If the `SELECT`-Statement just handles one `Near_By_Metadata__mdt`, everything works fine and i get all entries from the `Near_By_Table_Fields_Metadata`-Subquery in the right order. In my example, all three (one marked as header, two not marked).

But if the for-each-loop handles a second entry, the described problem occures. The second entry has the following `Near_By_Table_Fields_Metadata`: one marked as header and three not marked.

**INITIAL QUESTION**

I have some strange behaviour with one of my SOQL-Queries and i have absolutly no idea why this happens. Maybe someone here is able to help me.

I have the following for-each-loop with the query:

```
for(Near_By_Metadata__mdt nb : [SELECT Id, List_Overview_Header_API_Name__c, Object__r.QualifiedAPIName , Longitude_Field_API_Name__c, Latitude_Field_API_Name__c,
                Geolocation_Field__r.QualifiedAPIName, Marker_Color__c, LDS_Icon_Name__c, Additional_List_Info_Field_API_Name__c,
                (SELECT Field__r.QualifiedAPIName FROM Near_By_Detail_Fields_Metadata__r), (SELECT Field__r.QualifiedAPIName, Is_Header__c FROM Near_By_Table_Fields_Metadata__r ORDER BY Is_Header__c DESC)
                FROM Near_By_Metadata__mdt WHERE Is_Active__c = TRUE AND Object__r.QualifiedAPIName IN: objectsToSearchList])
```

The problem here ist the last subquery:

```
(SELECT Field__r.QualifiedAPIName, Is_Header__c FROM Near_By_Table_Fields_Metadata__r ORDER BY Is_Header__c DESC)
```

If i try, later in the code, to access all `Near_By_Table_Fields_Metadata__r` by using `nb.Near_By_Table_Fields_Metadata__r` it seems that salesforce discards or "forgot" some entries.

In example:

I have three entries of `Near_By_Table_Fields_Metadata` on one single `Near_By_Metadata__mdt` record. One with `Is_Header__c` set to TRUE and two set to FALSE.

If i am using the above query and trying to access the List i only get one entry. The one that is active. If i trying to `ORDER BY ASC` i got two entries. The two with the flag set to FALSE. And if i am removing the the whole `ORDER BY`, i got all values.

Does anyone has an idea what the problem could be here and how to solve it?